# Insert additional chapter with a letter suffix to prevent breaking existing numbering

Tags: numbering, chapters

Is there a way to add a chapter such that instead of incrementing the chapter number it takes the previous one and adds a letter suffix to it?

Reason being that I have a set of notes for a course I'm teaching. I already have printed some chapters for students and wish now to insert an additional chapter for this semester in the correct place, without disturbing the existing numbering.

```
\chapter{First original chapter}
% Numbered as Chapter 1

\chapter{Added chapter}
% I want this chapter to be Chapter 1A or 1a etc.

\chapter{Second original chapter}
% Numbered as Chapter 2
```

Comment: Do you need it to work with a table of contents, or merely with the chapter layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting the additional chapter in an `additional` environment does it:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newenvironment{additional}
{\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}\renewcommand{\thechapter}{ \arabic{chapter}A}}
{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First original chapter}
\begin{additional}
\chapter{Added chapter}
% I want this chapter to be Chapter 1A or 1a etc.
\end{additional}
\chapter{Second original chapter}
% Numbered as Chapter 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very clever!!!!

Comment: Very clever indeed!  Thank you!